# Why am I getting access denied when I try to replace files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to replace a file by basically copying a file named "test.csv" to "new.csv" But it cannot find test.csv even though its in the same working directory.

```
    def cop(self):
    with open('D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\betaapp2\\test.csv') as infile:
        with open('D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\betaapp2\\new.csv', 'w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
            # do things
                outfile.write(line)

    os.replace('D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\betaapp2\\new.csv', 'D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\betaapp2\\test.csv')




def sign_in(self, text_input):
    self.text_input = text_input
    count = 0
    h = ""
    d = ""
    with open('D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\betaapp2\\test.csv', 'r') as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh)
        # get the headers out first, which is the first line
        headers = next(reader)

        for line in reader:
            # this will make a dictionary with the header values as
            # keys and the line entries as values
            entry = dict(zip(headers, (l.strip() for l in line)))

            # use key access, it makes the code a bit more readable
            if entry['Name'] == text_input.strip():
                if entry['Position'] == "Vice President":
                    line[8] = float(line[8]) + 3.5
                    self.cop()
                    self.signin()

        else:
            self.noUser()
```

The test.csv is supposed to be updated by running sign_in and then copying it to new.csv. And then replace test.csv with new.csv.

Comment: I mean, this error raises when the file isn't found. Double- and triple-check that your working directory is what you think it is relative to "test.csv", otherwise, problem could always be avoided by passing the absolute path to the file. Also include error/stack trace in your question.

Comment: You should try to reduce this down to a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is not a minimal working example. There is lots of code that is unrelated to the problem. Most likely if you would reduce the code down to the actual problem, you would find the solution yourself.

Comment: Sooooo... one problem might be that you open the file with `open() as`, but then, while having it open, you call `self.cop()`, which in turn replaces the file you currently have open. DON'T use the same file in different ways simultaneously, that causes all sorts of problems. First close it, then replace it.

Answer (score 0):

They are in the same directory, but you haven't instructed Python to check that:

```
import os
base_path = "D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\betaapp2\\"

with open(os.path.join(base_path, "test.csv")) as infile:
    with open(os.path.join(base_path, "new.csv"), 'w') as outfile:
```

Without path Python just looks in the current working directory.

Comment: I don't think you should encourage him to hard-code directories even more.

Comment: Absolutely, particularly with that ugly MS Windows backslash - I just wanted to emphasize the error. EDIT: hardcoded part moved to variable

Comment: the `os.replace` call also uses relative path, could be problematic.

Comment: you can use `r'd:\johnp\kivy_venv\betaapp2\test.csv'` to avoid the double-slash

Comment: @DavidZemens Could. But double slash is totally valid. Perfect would be os.path.join, but as "C:" is very platform dependent, the separator really doesn't matter.

Comment: it kind of worked, it said I was accessed denied even though I used cmd with admin

Comment: @Finomnis yes, perfectly valid. but if one is concerned about how "ugly" it is to type path string with escaped backslashes, raw string is the way to go.

Comment: @david-zemens your answer with *raw* is correct, but one should use slash (not backslash) in such a case.